# overriding methods in Interface java

Tags: java, netbeans

I wrote an Interface in Java.
after that I tried to implement it by overriding as shown in the code.
but I get error that I have to add public before the method.

> why I have to add public ? why without public it does not work ?

as the Net-Beans says :  " attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public "

the code :

```
    package tryinginterface;
interface Bicycle {

    //  wheel revolutions per minute
    void changeCadence(int newValue);

    void changeGear(int newValue);

    void speedUp(int increment);

    void applyBrakes(int decrement);
}


class ACMEBicycle implements Bicycle {

    int cadence = 0;
    int speed = 0;
    int gear = 1;
    @Override 
        void changeCadence(int newValue) {
         cadence = newValue;
    }
    @Override
    void changeGear(int newValue) {
         gear = newValue;
    }
    @Override
    void speedUp(int increment) {
         speed = speed + increment;   
    }
    @Override
    void applyBrakes(int decrement) {
         speed = speed - decrement;
    }
    @Override
    void printStates() {
         System.out.println("cadence:" +
             cadence + " speed:" + 
             speed + " gear:" + gear);
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private?

Comment: @jhobbie: don't think so. this is about the difference between the implicit visibility between class and interface, not the definition of the various levels of visibility.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All methods in interfaces are public.

All methods in a class without a visibility modifier are package-private.

You cannot reduce the visibility of the public methods to package-private because it violates the interface.

Comment: Precisely. If you feel it helps, you can change all the methods in your interface to `public void` - this way it is clearer that the implementing methods should likewise be `public void`.

Comment: which is somewhat silly. implicit visibility in interface and in class is not the same, it always bugged me. same goes (even worse) for fields that are implicitly `public static final`

Comment: @njzk2 It has annoyed me that I can't explicitly say that a method/class is package-private. I have to leave out the declaration. My OCD is tingling.

Answer (score 3):

Because in an interface, all methods are by default **public**, and in a class, the default visibility of methods is **"friend"** - seen in the same package.

You can't narrow down the visibility when implementing a method, that's the rule.

Comment: "friend" is called package private in Java.

Answer (score 0):

lets suppose you have a interface Printable,which contains a method print().

```
interface Printable{
   int MIN=5;
   void print();
}
```

now because the method is declared inside interface , **compiler implicitly adds *public abstract* before the method**.
like this :-
[interface for compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cipG6.png)

now as the method is been declared public , so now when you extend the method you have to add public before the method.

*I think this might help you.*